# Ayuda Al filtrar Data desde el servidor con React

Tags: reactjs

alguien me dice como puedo agregarle una condición a los datos que llamo desde mi base de datos?
tengo una tabla Matricula donde los llamo todo, y lo que quiero es solo mostrar en un ReactTable los que tengan fecha de hoy..  Aquí el código

```
class Matricula extends Component {
    state = {
        datos:[],
        today: new Date()

    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
    this.fetchData()
    }
    fetchData = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await getAll('matricula') //llamo todos los registros
          console.log("ver: ", response.data); //en la consola puedo ver todas las matriculas Id, Fecha, nombre
          if (response.data.fecha.toLocaleString() === this.state.today.toLocaleDateString()) { // no se que me falta
          this.setState({
            status: "done",
            datos: response.data,
          });

        }
        } catch (error) {
          this.setState({
            status: "error"
          });
        }
      };



    render() {

        const data = this.state.matriculas;
        return (
                <ReactTable 
                    data={data} 
                    contentEditable
                    filterable
                    collapseOnDataChange={false}

          columns={[
                {
                  Header: "Id",
                  accessor: "id"
                },
                {
                  Header: "Name",
                  accessor: "Name"
                },
                {
                  Header: "Date",
                  accessor: "date",
                  id: "date",
                }

              ]
            }

          defaultPageSize={14}
          className="-striped -highlight"
        />
)}
export default Matricula;
```

Answer (score 0):

Eso es algo que podrías filtrar previamente en el servidor. De lo contrario,
si estás manejando fechas en JS te recomendaría usar la libreria moment.js.

Podrías hacer algo asi:

```
import moment from 'moment';

const iscurrentDate = moment(response.data.fecha).isSame(new Date());
if (iscurrentDate) {
  // Lanza tu condición
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pensando que tus fechas son objeto Date, haria algo como esto:

```
 let datosHoy = response.data.filter(item=>item.fecha.getTime() === this.state.today.getTime())
        this.setState({
            status: "done",
            datos: datosHoy,
          });
```